# How to implement Ragdoll physics to 2D characters in XNA?

Tags: xna, physics

I'm starting a new project with XNA. I want to create a game where the main character is subject to ragdoll physics when killed. I was wondering if anyone can give me any tips on how should I implement the character class and apply these ragdoll physics before I start coding so I don't have to refactor my code later. No code is necessary, just a basic overview of an algorithm and some tips. I've found a lot of information about ragdoll physics in 3D but nothig about 2D in XNA.

Comment: See this http://www.gamedev.net/topic/450217-2d-ragdoll-physics/

Comment: there is only one link given as an answer in that webpage and it is broken but thanks for helping anyway! :)

Comment: Yeah I wanted to give that forum post aswell to show that it's not only 3D. Didn't realize the link was broken, here is where it should've pointed: http://www.gpgstudy.com/gpgiki/GDC%202001%3A%20Advanced%20Character%20Physics

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot, It has a lot of good pointers. Why don't you put this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The Farseer physics engine supports 2D ragdolls and works with XNA. You might try that. http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As requested I've converted my comment to an answer*

Take a look at this paper http://www.gpgstudy.com/gpgiki/GDC%202001%3A%20Advanced%20Character%20Physics by Thomas Jakobsen, the ideas in there are as valid for 2D as they are for 3D.

Nic Foster (in the comments) also makes a good point that Farseer Physics supports 2D Ragdolls (I totally forgot about that) so that would be a good 'instant' solution and you can take a peak in the source code to see how it's done.